# Pidgin - Google Talk - How to display the dialpad

Tags: pidgin, google-talk, google-voice

I have Google Voice working with Google Talk and pidgin on my local computer.  My problem is that if I dial a conference number, I need a dial pad to enter the numbers, how can I get pidgin to display that?  Alternatively, if I can somehow enable it to capture the key presses, that'd be great too.  If I enter any numbers or characters, it doesn't appear to accept it.

Walter

Comment: How did you get Google Voice working in the desktop Google Talk client? I'd be interested to see how to do that.

Comment: I am using pidgin, it didn't require any configuration other than enabling the voice/video plugin.